# Elif: where is the invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hy guys.
I started Python yesterday with a book, but the code below is getting an err. What is wrong?

```
>>> temp = int(input('Entre com a temperatura: '))
Entre com a temperatura: 23
>>> if temp < 0:
        print('Congelando...')
        elif 0 <= temp <= 20:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Tried to change the tab but does not work either:

```
>>> temp = int(input('Entre com a temperatura: '))
Entre com a temperatura: 23
>>> if temp < 0:
        print('Congelando...')
    elif 0 <= temp <= 20:

SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>
```

Comment: The err occurs after I hit enter right after the colon. The sequence would be "print ('Frio')".

Comment: `elif` should be indented to the same level as `if`. The error is telling you that that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is spaces or tabs before the `elif`.  Try backspacing until `elif` is under the first character of the prompt `>>>`

Comment: Thats the thing! I tried here and it works... man that was newbie question :). Thanks all!